# One animation after another. Is there a better way to do this

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have been searching and trying different ways to do like the following code

```
  public void showActionButtons() {
    Animation a1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.floating_action_button_fade_in);
    Animation a2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.floating_action_button_fade_in);
    Animation a3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.floating_action_button_fade_in);


    a1.setStartOffset(300);
    m_proximityFloatingActionButton.startAnimation(a1);
    m_proximityFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    a2.setStartOffset(600);
    m_geofenceFloatingActionButton.startAnimation(a2);
    m_geofenceFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    a3.setStartOffset(900);
    m_locationFloatingActionButton.startAnimation(a3);
    m_locationFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
```

So what i am doing there is that i have 3 buttons that i want to popup one after another. I have tried different things. But this is the only thing that gave me the right results i was looking for. But this way feels wrong. It does not feel right to load 3 animations that is exactly the same. So is there another way that is the **best practice** of doing this?

Comment: see `android.animation.AnimatorSet` docs

Comment: In this case. How would you use AnimatorSet? Could you give me a good example? Not trying to be lazy or anything. Just want to know how you would recommend me using it

Comment: find a method to play `One animation after another`

Comment: Tried to figure out how i would use it but i failed. Need to use Animators. Something i do not know how. Would be helpful if you could give me an example.

Comment: see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml)

Comment: Good link. But i do not know how this should be used in my case. Because i have 3 buttons that needs to sequentially use the same animation. 

How would i set an Animator Set to affect multiple objects in that way. I can find how this is usefull if you have different animations for one object. But dont know how i would use it in my case

Comment: you want to play Animators sequentially, right?

Comment: yes exactly. But how do i assign one animator to one specific object. Because in this case i have three buttons. I dont find an issue to have 1 button do multiple animations. Just to make these three buttons work together

Comment: so read `AnimatorSet` docs and find a method to `"play Animatrors sequentially"`, read the API documentation

Comment: I have read the API documentation for it. I found the function to play animators sequentially. But it takes multiple animators. How do i assign animator1 to objectA and animator2 to objectB. I cant find that as a possibility with the AnimatorSet. I do understand how to play something sequentially with AnimatorSet in the way so it works like the following: animator1 and animator2 plays sequentially for objectA.

Comment: Animatro a1 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(....); a1.setTarget(objectA); Animatro a2 = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(....); a2.setTarget(objectB); AnimatorSet.playSequentially(a1, a2);

Answer (score 0):

So with the help from pskink i got the following code. If anyone have a better way to do this. You are welcome to post your answer

```
  public void showActionButtons() {
    ObjectAnimator a1 = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.fragment_floating_action_button_fade_in);
    ObjectAnimator a2 = a1.clone();
    ObjectAnimator a3 = a1.clone();

    FloatingActionButtonAdapter adapter = new FloatingActionButtonAdapter();

    a1.addListener(adapter);
    a2.addListener(adapter);
    a3.addListener(adapter);

    a1.setTarget(m_proximityFloatingActionButton);
    a2.setTarget(m_geofenceFloatingActionButton);
    a3.setTarget(m_locationFloatingActionButton);

    AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.playSequentially(a1, a2, a3);

    animatorSet.start();
  }

  private class FloatingActionButtonAdapter extends AnimatorListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
      ((View)((ObjectAnimator) animation).getTarget()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Agreed with the way you are doing it but you can also do it in xml by using < set >.

Comment: use `AnimatorListenerAdapter` instead of `AnimatorListener`, less code

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use open source libraries, [android transition](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition) library offers an easier to write and understand alternative.

Assuming the 3 buttons are the only children of a ViewGroup, the code below will produce the same result:

```
            Cascade cascade = new Cascade(Cascade.SEQUENTIAL, 0.9f);
            ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(findViewById(R.id.lay_buttons)).alpha(0f, 1f).visible().transitViewGroup(new ViewTransitionBuilder.ViewGroupTransition() {
                @Override
                public void transit(ViewTransitionBuilder builder, ViewTransitionBuilder.ViewGroupTransitionConfig config) {
                    builder.buildAnimationFor(animationManager);
                }
            }, cascade);
            animationManager.startAnimation(600);
```

Basically a [`ViewTransitionBuilder`](https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition/blob/5fc6f1f08267db948567b6f35cdd15761420f822/core/src/main/java/com/kaichunlin/transition/ViewTransitionBuilder.java) is used to specify the desired effect, and `ViewTransitionBuilder.ViewGroupTransition` is used to traverse each child of the target view (`R.id.lay_buttons`), and builds an animation out of it that's added to `animationManager`.

Alternatively, if the 3 buttons are *not* in the same ViewGroup, the code below would work:

```
        ViewTransitionBuilder builder=ViewTransitionBuilder.transit(findViewById(R.id.lay_buttons)).alpha(0f, 1f).visible();
        builder.clone().range(0f, 0.33f).target(findViewById(R.id.rotate_android)).buildAnimationFor(animationManager);
        builder.clone().range(0.33f, 0.67f).target(findViewById(R.id.slide_subviews)).buildAnimationFor(animationManager);
        builder.clone().range(0.67f, 1f).target(findViewById(R.id.slide_bg)).buildAnimationFor(animationManager);
        animationManager.startAnimation(600);
```

To start using the library add the following gradle script:

> compile 'com.github.kaichunlin.transition:core:0.9.3'